# Date time difference in minutes python

Tags: python, python-datetime, python-3.9

I'm new to python and tiring to calculate time difference in minutes. Times are in slightly  two different formats. I have tried below to format but did not got it correctly

```
from datetime import datetime
start = "2023-05-21T11:40:54.532203+00:00"
end = "2023-05-21T11:45:00+00:00"

starttime=datetime.strptime(start , "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%f%z'")
endtime=datetime.strptime(end , "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%f%z'")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

start = "2023-05-21T11:40:54.532203+00:00"
end = "2023-05-21T11:45:00+00:00"


def time_diff(start,end):
    start = datetime.strptime(start,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
    end = datetime.strptime(end,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
    ##return in minutes
    return (end - start).total_seconds() / 60

print(time_diff(start,end))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

start = "2023-05-21T11:40:54.532203+00:00"
end = "2023-05-21T11:45:00+00:00"

starttime = datetime.strptime(start, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
endtime = datetime.strptime(end, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

Now, to find the time difference in minutes, you can subtract `starttime` from `endtime` and use the `total_seconds()` function to get the difference in seconds. Then, you can divide by 60 to convert it to minutes:

```
time_difference = endtime - starttime
minutes_difference = time_difference.total_seconds() / 60
print(minutes_difference)
```

I got `4.09112995`.